# hide many button with next and preview button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have ten buttons with a button for next and previous,
when I click the next button, it should show the next two buttons (hiding the rest).
The reverse should happen when the previous button is clicked (Show the previous two buttons (hide the rest)).

thanks.

my html code is :

```
<div>
<button class="menu">M1</button>
<button class="menu">M2</button>
<button class="menu">M3</button>
<button class="menu">M4</button>
<button class="menu">M5</button>
<button class="menu">M6</button>
<button class="menu">M7</button>
<button class="menu">M8</button>
<button class="menu">M9</button>
<button class="menu">M10</button>
</div>
<div>
<button class="action" id="btnNext">Next</button>
<button class="action" id="btnPreview">Previous</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Am i correct in understanding that you only want two buttons displayed at a time? Clicking next/prev shows the next/prev two buttons?

Comment: Yes you are understanding

Answer (score 1):

Initially make every button hidden except first two.

```
$("#btnNext").on('click', function(){
    var vBtn = $(".menu:visible:last");
    $(".menu").hide();
    vBtn.next().show();
    vBtn.next().next().show();
});

$("#btnPreview").on('click', function(){
    var vBtn = $(".menu:visible:first");
    $(".menu").hide();
    vBtn.prev().show();
    vBtn.prev().prev().show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I manually coded not tested please check

```
$("button.menu").not(':eq(0),:eq(1)').hide();
var count = 1;
$("#btnNext").click(function() {
       $("button.menu").hide();
       count = count + 2;
       $("button.menu").eq(count-1).show();
       $("button.menu").eq(count).show();
});

$("#btnPreview").click(function() {
       $("button.menu").hide();
       count = count - 2;
       $("button.menu").eq(count-1).show();
       $("button.menu").eq(count).show();
});
```